# Accessing factory properties in AngularJS + Chrome Apps APIs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, google-chrome-app

I'm attempting to build a Chrome App using AngularJS, and one of the abilities I need is to monitor the available network interfaces through [chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_network). Currently, I am trying to store this data in a factory and inject it into the view controller:

(pared down as much as possible)

Factory:

```
exampleApp.factory('exampleFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.network_interfaces = 'Detecting network connections...';

    chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function(interfaces){
      service.network_interfaces = interfaces;
    })

    // This outputs the expected array containing interface data
    // in service.network_interfaces
    console.log(service)

    return service;
}]);
```

Controller:

```
exampleApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'exampleFactory', function($scope, $http, exampleFactory) {
    // This outputs the expected array in network_interfaces, identical
    // to the console output within the factory
    console.log(exampleFactory)

    // But then this outputs the initial 'Detecting network connections...'
    // string set in the factory
    console.log(exampleFactory.network_interfaces)

    // And {{network_interfaces}} and {{factory_state}} in the view keep
    // 'Detecting network connections...' as the value for network_interfaces
    // permanently
    $scope.factory_state = exampleFactory;
    $scope.network_interfaces = exampleFactory.network_interfaces;
}]);
```

So:

1. The factory seems to be returning a good `service` object, but I'm not sure why `exampleFactory` and `exampleFactory.network_interfaces` would have the different states they do between the controller and factory, and especially within the controller itself (regardless of the order they're called in).
2. I've attempted a lot of different solutions with the hypothesis that it's an asynch issue, but I would think there'd be no appreciable latency on the `getNetworkInterfaces` method and if there were that everything is set up correctly for Angular to update the `{{network_interfaces}}` and `{{factory_state}}` view bindings once data is returned.
3. I've also tried wrapping various functions in the factory with `$rootScope.$apply` as a shot in the dark, but with the same results as above.

I've searched around a lot to discover whatever concept it is I've obviously missed, but I think I'm overlooking something fundamental. How to I get the getNetworkInterfaces() data into my controller in a useful state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption in #2 is the problem. There will *always* be a spin of the JavaScript event loop in between a call to an asynchronous method and the invocation of its callback. If there weren't, all sorts of things would subtly break in clients calling the method. This means you are encountering a common problem in Angular development: that you don't get notified that something changed, because the change didn't happen within the context of Angular's digest cycle.

To fix this: try setting up a watch, then calling $scope.apply() within the getNetworkInterfaces() callback. The apply() is guaranteed to happen outside the digest cycle so you shouldn't get an apply-in-apply error.

Alternatively, post a message to yourself when then callback is done. This is better if you're a student of the "if you're using apply() your code is broken" school of thought.

Finally, consider a Promise that you call after the callback. This doesn't quite fit how you've set up your code.

(Also, why call the async method at all in the factory?)

Comment: Disclaimer: as many people do, I find AngularJS change detection confusing, especially when mixed with asynchronous methods like those in the Chrome platform. It's possible I've given you bad advice.

Comment: _(Also, why call the async method at all in the factory?)_
Oh wow, why indeed. I've only done simple projects with Angular, so I was clinging to the "keep shared data/states out of controllers" mantra rather ineptly. I've left the `getNetworkInterfaces` method in the factory as `service.network_interfaces`, but moved the invocation of it into the controller and it works perfectly as expected now.

Comment: I put console.log('this is a hack/pause'); in the controller just before the controller's return, and Chrome started displaying data from my factory. I could have spent days on this weirdness. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try watching on network_interfaces to know when it's modified

```
exampleApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'exampleFactory', function($scope, $http, exampleFactory) {
    // This outputs the expected array in network_interfaces, identical
    // to the console output within the factory
    console.log(exampleFactory)

    // But then this outputs the initial 'Detecting network connections...'
    // string set in the factory
    console.log(exampleFactory.network_interfaces)

    // And {{network_interfaces}} and {{factory_state}} in the view keep
    // 'Detecting network connections...' as the value for network_interfaces
    // permanently
    $scope.factory_state = exampleFactory;
    $scope.network_interfaces = exampleFactory.network_interfaces;

    $scope.$watch('factory_state.network_interfaces', function() {
       console.log($scope.factory_state)
   });
}]);
```

Comment: It still shows the same odd behavior unfortunately:

`$scope.$watch('factory_state.network_interfaces', function() {
      console.log(exampleFactory)
      console.log(exampleFactory.network_interfaces)
    });`
    
The first console output has the expected data in network_interfaces, the second console output still has the original string.

Comment: That wouldn't work because the Chrome callback wouldn't trigger Angular's change detection in its digest cycle.